# Uploading Zip file with Nuxt.js

Tags: express, amazon-s3, file-upload, nuxt.js, zip

I am trying to add functionality to my Nuxt.js app to allow users to upload zip files. When this file is uploaded I want to POST it to an Express backend, from there I will upload to AWS S3.

I am getting errors on the last step because the file that I am trying to upload is actually a JavaScript Object containing metadata about the file, but doesnt seem to have the file contents itself. I presume I need to get the data of the file and convert it to a Buffer array, but I can't seem to find where that data is! So although the error is coming from the uploading to S3 part, I think the problem is caused by sending the wrong data from the Nuxt app.

This is the error when uploading the file to S3:

```
Error [TypeError]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object
```

The object looks like this. This is the 'file' that I am sending from the Nuxt frontend to the Express backend:

```
{
    lastModified: 1688470696734
    lastModifiedDate: Tue Jul 04 2023 13:38:16 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) 
    name: "test.zip"
    size: 1406
    type: "application/zip"
    webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

The Nuxt code is:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="submitFile()">
            <input id="#file" type="file" @change="handleFileUpload($event)">
            <br>
            <b-button id="form-button" type="submit" variant="primary" class="button">
                save
            </b-button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
  
<script>

export default {
    name: "FileUpload",
    components: {},
    data () {
        return {
            file: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submitFile () {
            try {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', this.file);
                this.$axios.post(`/api/uploadFile`, formData, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                })
            } catch (err) {
                console.log({ err })
            }
        },
        handleFileUpload (event) {
            console.log(event)
            this.file = event.target.files[0];

        }
    }
};
</script>
```

The Express endpoint code is:

```
app.post("/uploadFile", checkAuthToken, async function (req, res, next) {
    const upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: bucketName,
            // acl: 'public-read', // Set the appropriate ACL for the uploaded file
            metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
            },
            key: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, Date.now().toString()); // Set a unique key for the uploaded file
            },
        }),
    });
    upload.single('file')(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            // Handle multer-specific errors
            console.error('Multer error:', err);
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Multer error' });
        } else if (err) {
            // Handle other errors
            console.error('Error uploading file:', err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'File upload failed' });
        }

        // File uploaded successfully
        console.log('File uploaded:', req.file);
        const params = {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: fileName,
            Body: file,
        };

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(data.Location);
                }
            });
        });
        return res.json({ key: req.file.key });
    });
})
```